# Printing *'s as an arrow in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So I've given it my best shot and I'm really wracking my brain in trying to come up with a solution to finishing this problem. This type of question has been asked before on here but this time it's with a twist.

So I'm supposed to print a left pointing arrow such as this:

```
  public class Arrow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  int n = 0;

  if (args.length < 1) {

     System.out.println("Input a value.");
     System.exit(0);  

  }      
  else {

     n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  }

  for (int rows = 1; rows <= n; rows++) {//This tells how many lines to print (height)

    for (int numSpaces = 0; numSpaces < (n - rows); numSpaces++) {//Prints spaces before the '*'
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    for (int numStars = 0; numStars < rows; numStars++) { //Prints the " " first in each line then a "*".  
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println(""); //Next Line         

  }

  for (int rows = 1; rows <= n; rows++) {//This tells how many lines to print (height)

    for (int numSpaces = n; numSpaces > (n - rows); numSpaces--) {//Prints spaces before the '*'
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    for (int numStars = n; numStars > rows; numStars--) { //Prints the " " first in each line then a "*".  
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println(""); //Next Line         

    }       

 }

}

        *
       **
      ***
     ****
    *****
     ****
      ***
       **
        *
```

Now the issue I'm running into is that the arrow should have a middle piece sticking out the back end equivalent to the length of n + (n - 1). I can't figure out how to do it because I'm new to loops and I've spent the better part of 2 hours trying to get it right.

Can some kind soul please please pleeeease help me out lol.

Thanks

Comment: Well.. What's the exact pattern you need? Can we see that?

Answer (score 0):

I have just added an if block within your first big `for` loop. Lookout for `// This is where the tail of the arrow starts` and `// This is where the tail of the arrow ends`. I have kept tail length as `2*n` for now, you could change it as per your need, say to `3*n` or something else.

An `if` check helps to evaluate a condition and take corresponding action:

```
  for (int rows = 1; rows <= n; rows++) {//This tells how many lines to print (height)

    for (int numSpaces = 0; numSpaces < (n - rows); numSpaces++) {//Prints spaces before the '*'
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    for (int numStars = 0; numStars < rows; numStars++) { //Prints the " " first in each line then a "*".  
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    // This is where the tail of the arrow starts
    if(rows==n) { 
        // Decide the length of the tail of the arrow here. It is currently 2*n below
        for(int arrowLength = 1; arrowLength <= 2*n; arrowLength++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    // This is where the tail of the arrow ends
    System.out.println(""); //Next Line         
  }
```

Output with input as 10:

```
                  *
                **
              ***
            ****
          *****
        ******
      *******
    ********
  *********
******************************
  *********
    ********
      *******
        ******
          *****
            ****
              ***
                **
                  *
```